# Does Welches method in python (scipy.signal.welch) use any truncation or digital anti-aliasing filtering?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

[Power spectral density plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K92mh.png)

In the power spectral density estimation, as shown above ([reference](https://sapienlabs.org/lab-talk/factors-that-impact-power-spectrum-density-estimation/)), there is a roll-off happening at the right end (like a sharp cut-off) in frequency close to half the sampling frequency, which is the Nyquist frequency (close to 90 Hz in the above-shown example). Is it caused by some specific function of the "scipy.signal.welch" in python? For example, the number of points per sample, windowing techniques, truncation, or the overlap?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is caused by anti-aliasing filter. Welch method does not cause the truncation.

You can test it yourself, made little snippet, comparing psd with `abs(fft(x))` for two signals (100 and 500Hz at 1kHz sampling frequency). Welch method does not cut 500Hz.

```
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# making highest frequency signal 1, -1, 1, -1
signal1 = (np.arange(1000) % 2) * 2 - 1
signal2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*100*np.linspace(0, 1, 1000))
signal = signal1 + signal2

psd = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal))
freq_domain, psd_welch = scipy.signal.welch(signal, scaling='density')
psd_welch = psd_welch * 6  # changing scale to compare for easier comparison on plot

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 1, len(psd)), psd)
plt.plot(freq_domain, psd_welch, 'r--')
plt.show()
```

[image]